# any npm package to run grep against list of path?

Tags: javascript, typescript, grep

I tried to look for a package that can run a grep filter against an array of string. But I can't find one.

I want to do something like this:

```
const paths = ['some/file/paths-1', 'some/other/paths', ... ]
const filteredPaths = grep(paths, 'some/file/**/*')
```

I understand this question is not a good SO question as it can be opinionated and favor a particular package.

But I think many people would look for the same thing.

Comment: Requests for libraries are off-topic.

Comment: If you know something is not a good SO question, don't post it. Use Quora or Reddit or some other venue less concerned with quality.

Comment: "I know this is off-topic".  Then don't ask it.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't make any sense to try and use grep to solve this. Javascript regexes work just fine.

```
const paths = ['some/file/paths-1', 'some/other/paths', ... ]
const filteredPaths = paths.filter(path => /^some\/file\/.*/)
```

if you insist on using grep for this you could do it like so:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync
const paths = ['some/file/paths-1', 'some/other/paths']
fs.writeFileSync('/tmp/b', paths.join('\n'), 'utf8')
const grepResult = execSync("grep 'some/file/' /tmp/b")
const filteredPaths = grepResult.toString()
console.log(filteredPaths)
```

I personally fail to see any situation that this appropriate though

Answer (score 0):

I found it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/matcher

This is useful if you are getting input from cli or config.
Regex in those cases would be too complicated.

Sometimes finding the right package for the job is hard, it is even harder today with https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19438

I'd leave the question and answer here so that people can find it a bit easier.